# Failled to load the plugins manager in Apache Jemeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I am trying to install a plugin from the plugin manager and I did the installation by downloading a file and kept in the lib\ext folder and restarted the Jemeter and I clicked on the option from the tools menu and clicked on the plugins manager it shows an bellow error !

```
`Java.net.connectExcemption : Connection Timed out : no further information 
 at java.base/sun nio.ch.Net.Pollconnect (Native method )
 at java.base/sun nio.ch.Net.PollConnectNow (Net Java:672) ... Etc`
```

I have tried Restart the system and try to access plugins manager but still facing the same kinda issue !

Answer (score 0):

Its says connection timeout - May be you are running JMeter behind the proxy. Check your proxy configuration and If you have one - Then, try starting the JMeter with the proxy

```
jmeter -H <Proxy host> -P <Proxy port> -u username -a password
```

Here username and password are optional, use it only if you need credentials for accessing the internet via proxy

Comment: Where we have to run these command ? And how can I know the proxy host and port details ?

Comment: you need to execute this in commandline - Alternatively, you can set the value in system.properties as well like below 

http.proxyHost=<Proxy host>
http.proxyPort=<Proxy port>
https.proxyHost=<Proxy host>
https.proxyPort=<Proxy port>

Proxy configuration can be seen in Internet Options -> Lan settings in browser

Or you can execute inetcpl.cpl in run prompt -> Lan Settings

Answer (score 0):

It means that the plugins manager cannot connect to the plugins repository which is located at https://jmeter-plugins.org/repo/

Try if you can access it using [curl](https://curl.se/) or [wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) or equivalent and if you cannot - it's not a JMeter problem, you need to inspect your machine network configuration and make sure that it's capable of reaching out to the plugins repository.

If you're behind a corporate proxy - you need to make JMeter [aware of this proxy.](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server)

If the proxy is using a MITM certificate - you need to import it to the [Java Truststore](https://www.baeldung.com/java-keystore-truststore-difference) and make JMeter aware of this truststore by specifying the relevant [JMeter system properties](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization)

More information: [JMeter Plugins Manager Network Configuration](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManagerNetworkConfiguration/)